# Can't iterate into javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I come to you because i have some issues using javascript arrays.

I'm trying to iterates through a javascript array filled with some objects.
I have totally 4 objects.

this is my code :

```
// sort trainings_tab descending order
trainings_tab = trainings_tab.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.date_from < b.date_from)
        return 1;
    else if(a.date_from > b.date_from)
        return -1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(trainings_tab);
for(var h = 0; h < trainings_tab.length; h++) {

    // var training = new_array[h];
    console.log(trainings_tab[h]);
}
```

and what i've got from console.log(trainings_tab); =>

```
[] (i have a little blue i here that say : object value at left was snapshotted when logged value below was evaluated just now)
 0: Object
    _geoloc: Object
    _highlightResult: Object
    _rankingInfo: Object
    address: "Hospital da plastica, Rio de Janeiro, Brazil"
    address_id: 16623
    date_from: "1479769200"
    date_to: "1480028400"
    device: "USD"
    doctor_full_name: "John Doe"
    doctor_id: "85"
    doctor_image: "/images/avatar_85.jpg"
    doctor_url: "/profile/85"
    guest: "2"
    labo_id: "8So7KJPmv4qyL2uHD"
    langues: "English"
    objectID: "689"
    objectives: Array[2]
    price: "1000"
    procedures: Array[1]
    products: Array[1]
    seat_left: "2"
    seat_taken: 0
    speciality: "PLASTIC SURGERY, BODY CONTOURING"
    training_full: ""
    training_name: "Lipofacillomaxial"
    url: "/training/detail/689"
    __proto__: Object
 1: Object
 2: Object
 3: Object
 length: 4
 __proto__: Array[0]
```

Each objects looks like the first one, with other datas ofc.
But the problem is that my for loop doesn't iterate other the array and i can't see the console.log(trainings_tab[h]);

Someone has an idea and can help me plz ? Thanks.

**EDIT : HOW DO I POPULATE MY TAB ?**

i assign a var at empty tab :

```
var trainings_tab = [];
```

I use ALGOLIA (https://www.algolia.com/) to search into an index called 'training' and that get all my records. When the search is done i have a callback and i'm doing this :

```
function searchDone(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        //console.log(content.hits);
        for(var i = 0; i < content.hits.length; i++) {
            var training = content.hits[i];

            // check that's a training
            if (training && training.date_from != null) {
                // calculate  seats taken
                var seats_taken = training.guest - training.seat_left;

                var training_full = '';
                // training is full ?
                if (training.seat_left == 0) training_full = 'training-full';

                training.seat_taken = seats_taken;
                training.training_full = training_full;

                if (training.hidden == false || training.hidden == null)
                    Session.set("countTrainings", Session.get("countTrainings")+1);

                trainings_tab.push(training);
            }
        }

    }
```

It seems that my problem is when i populate the trainings_tab, because if i console.log before the sort, i have the same display than quoted before...

Comment: Sounds like the problem is how you're populating `trainings_tab` in the first place, which you haven't shown. It sounds like you've put the same object into the array four times, rather than putting four different objects in the array.

Comment: nrelated: There's no need to reassign back to `trainings_tab` here: `trainings_tab = trainings_tab.sort(...)`. `sort` sorts the array *in place*, it doesn't create a new array.

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: I can assure you that the fourth objects are all differents.
Thanks for the sort, didn't know, but that didn't solve my problem :/

Comment: No errors in the console Weedoze.